# Como usar LEAD e LAG usando uma condição

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tsql, sql-server-2012

Minha dúvida é, se consigo usar o LAG e LEAD, usando uma condição na query, por exemplo:

Tenho a coluna cep..

quero pegar o valor da próxima linha, e o valor da linha anterior dessa mesma coluna..
Estou trabalhando com c# e SQL server 2012.. mas fazer uma lista no c# com todos os resultados é inviável, são quase 600 mil registros.

fiz um teste com LAG e LEAD

```
SELECT
LAG(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) CidadeAnte,
cid_nucep AS CidadeAtual,
LEAD(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) ProxCidade
FROM bcadcida
GO
```

O retorno foi perto do que preciso:

NULL          87365000    68912350
87365000    68912350    48320000
68912350    48320000    74423970

Porém, se uso uma condição:

```
SELECT
LAG(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) CidadeAnte,
cid_nucep AS CidadeAtual,
LEAD(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) ProxCidade
FROM bcadcida where cid_nucep = 77777777
GO
```

O resultado é falho..

NULL    77777777    NULL

Como posso pegar por o valor de cid_nucep, da linha anterior, e da proxima minha?

Comment: Se uma condição é passada cid_nucep = 77777777 então não existirá nada anterior nem posterior a esta condição ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumo que sua tabela seja assim (nesta ordem):

```
cid_nomec | cid_nucep 
(nome)      87365000 
(nome)      68912350 
(nome)      48320000 
(nome)      74423970
```

Em algum lugar há este CEP `77777777`:

```
cid_nomec | cid_nucep 
...
(nome)      77777777
...
```

O problema é que você restringiu a consulta a um resultado que traz uma linha só, portanto `LEAD` e `LAG` virão nulos porque não há elementos anteriores ou posteriores.

Se bem entendi o que você quer, você quer passar um CEP para a consulta e obter os valores de `LEAD` e `LAG` dela. Isso se faz da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CidadeAnte, CidadeAtual, ProxCidade from
    (SELECT
        LAG(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) CidadeAnte,
        cid_nucep AS CidadeAtual,
        LEAD(cid_nucep) OVER (ORDER BY cid_nomec) ProxCidade
        FROM bcadcida
    )
WHERE CidadeAtual = 77777777

GO
```