# Select pegando linha anterior

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

O que tenho que usar no SQL SERVER 2008 para pegar a linha anterior a uma determinada clausura. Por exemplo se no meu where abaixo se o alerta for = a 99 quero saber o alerta e a velocidade anterior ao alerta.

```
Speed     Data                  Alerta
58   '2017-09-13 10:08:04.290'  44
20   '2017-09-13 10:08:51.340'  99
56   '2017-09-13 10:09:21.450'  204
40   '2017-09-13 10:09:27.470'  99
34   '2017-09-13 10:09:37.570'  204
```

Neste exemplo houve dois alerta 99 onde ele estava a uma velocidade de 20 e 40 km, quero retornar esta linha anterior ao alerta com a maior velocidade:

```
Speed     Data                  Alerta
56   '2017-09-13 10:09:21.450'  204
```

Comment: Não seria a 58   '2017-09-13 10:08:04.290'  44 de maior velocidade ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar LEAD e LAG usando uma condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14317/como-usar-lead-e-lag-usando-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: @MarceloMartins: A tabela possui coluna que identifique cada linha de forma única? Isto é, possui chave primária?  // E se houver mais de um alerta 99, mas com a mesma velocidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um pouco grande, mas resolve seu problema..

```
declare @Velocidades table
(
    Speed int,
    Data Datetime,
    Alerta int
);


insert into @Velocidades  values
(58,'2017-09-13 10:08:04.290',44),
(20,'2017-09-13 10:08:51.340',99),
(56,'2017-09-13 10:09:21.450',204),
(40,'2017-09-13 10:09:27.470',99),
(34,'2017-09-13 10:09:37.570',204)

declare @VelocidadesTeste table
(
    Speed int,
    Data Datetime,
    Alerta int
);


DECLARE @Speed int, @Data Datetime, @Alerta int;  

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT Speed, Data, Alerta
    FROM @Velocidades
    WHERE Alerta = 99; 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Speed, @Data, @Alerta   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       insert into @VelocidadesTeste
       select top 1 * from @Velocidades 
       where Data < @Data 
       order by Data desc;

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Speed, @Data, @Alerta   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


select * from @VelocidadesTeste
where Speed = (select max(Speed) from @VelocidadesTeste)
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Eis sugestão para a versão 2008 do SQL Server:

```
-- código #1
with 
Alerta99 as (
SELECT Data, 
       Seq= row_number() over (order by Speed desc)
  from tbAlerta
  where alerta = 99
),
MaiorVelocidade99 as (
SELECT Data
  from Alerta99
  where Seq = 1
)
SELECT top (1) Speed, Data, Alerta
  from tbAlerta as A
  where A.Data < (SELECT Data from MaiorVelocidade99)
  order by A.Data desc;
```

A CTE Alerta99 separa todas as linhas cujo alerta seja 99 e cria coluna com sequência delas, iniciando pela de maior velocidade e incrementando à medida que a velocidade decresce.

A CTE MaiorVelocidade99 obtém a data da linha de maior velocidade, para o alerta 99.

Ao final é retornada a linha imediatamente anterior à linha de maior velocidade para alerta 99, utilizando a data como critério.

Não testado; pode conter erros.